# nginx - error pages not working

Tags: nginx, server

My custom error pages used to work, however now I am getting the error `No input file specified` whenever an error page is thrown; however if I access it directly, such as `www.example.com/404`, it is displayed correctly.

Why is this? I can't see anything wrong with my configuration. All my pages are in the same folder too, so I don't see how I am getting this error.

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myserver.key;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-$
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;

# HTTPS redirect

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    rewrite ^ https://www.example.com$request_uri? permanent;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains";
    resolver 192.0.2.1;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    keepalive_timeout 70;
    access_log /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log;
    root /var/www/example.com/public_html/example/public/_main;
    server_name example.com;

    # HSTS - 6 months
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains";
    resolver 192.0.2.1;

    error_page 400 = /400.php;
    error_page 401 = /401.php;
    error_page 403 = /403.php;
    error_page 404 = /404.php;
    error_page 500 = /500.php;
    error_page 503 = /503.php;

    # Remove trailing slash to please routing system.
    if (!-d $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    location  /400.php {
            internal;
    }
    location  /401.php {
            internal;
    }
    location  /403.php {
            internal;
    }
    location  /404.php {
            internal;
    }
    location  /500.php {
            internal;
    }
    location  /503.php {
            internal;
    }

    location = / {
            index landing.php;
    }
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /assets/images/ {
            valid_referers none blocked example.com *.example.com;
            if ($invalid_referer) {
                    return 403;
            }
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            if ($uri !~ "^/assets/images/") {
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
            }
            fastcgi_index landing.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

Comment: Questions on OS configuration and infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to fix this. In the `location ~ \.php$ { }` block, you need to add `fastcgi_intercept_errors on;`. It will end up looking like this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            if ($uri !~ "^/assets/images/") {
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
            }
            fastcgi_index landing.php;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was this line:

```
try_files $uri =404;
```